# Open source BPM with web based UI form designer?

Tags: forms, business-process-management

Does anybody know of any open source BPM products that include a good web based UI form designer?

I've seen Joget which looks good.  Anything else?

Answer (score 5):

Alfresco's Activiti (http://www.activiti.org) BPM Engine is probably the most widely used open source BM product. It is released under the Apache 2 license making it considerable more appealing for commercial applications than Joget (GPL License).
When Activiti is combined with BP3's Brazos ( http://bp-3.com/activiti ) UI and Portal technologies, you have an enterprise class Open Source BPM environment.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my feedback on some opensource BPMS (java based).

- Bonitasoft BPM. The most advanced studio for processes and forms, but it's an installed program.
- Activity. Modelization is based on eclipse plugins. If I remember well, you can't modify form in a web designer. You can also design forms based with XML.
- JBPM. Comes with a web based designer for processes and form. It's what you're looking for I think.
- Camunda. It does not bring form designer yet so you have to design them using XML.

Bonitasoft BPM may be the simpliest to use. Camunda is my favourite for its features and how it is finished. jBPM brings some nice features (like a rules engine) but looks very complicated at first. And activity may be the most open software but it lacks QA.

Hope it helps, feel free to give us feedback on which one you choose as I'm also interested :)